# The simplest time synchronize method

Tags: java, winapi, time, gps, ntp

I have a system written on Java. It's exchanging with another system using protocol upon rs485 that has a GPS receiver. So i can query time from java program and another system returns current time from GPS receiver. Using special timestamps i can compute transmission delay like in SNTP and set system time. 
The question is: what is the simplest way to set the system time on windows machine from Java program?
I've two ideas:
1) writing shell script, that is called from java code and sets current system time using DATE and TIME commands. Things i don't like: two command usage and setting system time is an admin procedure that turns on UAC user confirmation;
2) implementing a Time Provider dll (using API in [Microsoft doc reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725475(v=vs.85).aspx)). Java program will exchange with code in dll using simple protocol using IPC or some IP based transport. So setting system time is the w32tm service responsibility. But this idea seems too complex.

P.S. in future this question may arise for java system deployed on Linux computers.

Any ideas?

Comment: To set the system time on Windows you call [SetSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942.aspx).